# Component takes long time to render list randomly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I am experiencing a weird behaviour with one of my components. The component loads a list of objects from a service in the `ngOInit()`.
The issue I am facing is totally random, sometimes it takes a lot of time to render this list and sometimes it is immediate.
I have ruled out it is a backend issue, the calls to the backend are always fast. I have found the following. After adding the hook `DoCheck` I've seen when the issue mentioned happens it takes quite some time since the `ngOnInit()` reaches the end and the `ngDoCheck()` is called.

According to Angular's documentation `ngDoCheck()` is called after `ngOnIni()` so I don't fully understand why this takes so long sometimes. I have added `console.log` with a time to have the execution time of each call-
I've added the log after at the last line of `ngOnInit()`, when the call to get the list of objects is actually done and in the `ngDoCheck()`.

This is how the browser console looks like when it takes a lot of time:

[image: console]

As you can see it has finished the `ngOnInit()`, then done `ngDoCheck()`, finishes getting the items and then after 10 seconds it runs `ngDoCheck()` which when the list is actually rendered in the screen.

This is part of the component's code with the `ngOnInit()` and `ngDoCheck()`:

```
  ngDoCheck(){
    console.log('ngDoCheck. N. Items ' + this.items.length, new Date());
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.sensorTypeConfigEndpoint.getInheritedType().then(result => {
      this.typeInherited = result;
      if (this._markers) {
        const groups = this._markers.map(marker => marker.get('group'));
        if (groups && groups.length) {
          this.getItemsByMapVisualization(this.typeViewMap, _.cloneDeep(groups)).then( items => {
            this.items = items;
            console.log('items N. Items ' + this.items.length, new Date())
            this.isLoading = false;
          });
        }
      }
    });
    console.log('ngOnInit N. Items ' + this.items.length, new Date())
  }
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div class="flex-cards" [ngStyle]="{'max-height': maxHeight}" [class.columnWrap]="isClusterInside" [appLoading]="isLoading">
  <div (click)="expand()" *ngIf="isClusterInside" class="grid-expand">
    <img class="filter-grey" src="assets/images/expand_cluster.svg" alt="Expand" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;margin-left: 4px">
    <p class="text-expand" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
      Expandir
    </p>
  </div>
  <section class="card" style="height: calc(100% - 12px); overflow-y: auto;">
    <div class="content-card">
      <div *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{item.text}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Any idea of why the list might be taking so long to render? It happens randomly.

Comment: From what I understand, `'items N. Items '` is your last log. It comes when everything is done. But this log comes quickly. In the console, `ngOnInit` logs at 08:56:23, and the last log, `'items N. Items '`, arrives at... 08:56:23, within the same second. Then you have a bunch of `ngDoCheck()` logs, but this is nothing, all the core logic has already been done. I'm not sure I understand where the problem is

Comment: The problem is that when all the logic is done, the HTML hasn't rendered the list. It actually does when the second `ngDoCheck()` comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sensorTypeConfigEndpoint` looks like something that's "out of Angular's world". When it makes some changes to `this.items` and `this.isLoading`, Angular doesn't realize it and doesn't redraw the view.

It's like Angular is sleeping, because it sees no change happen. `ngDoCheck()` kind of "wakes" Angular up and forces it to take the change into consideration and redraw the view, but the wake is a side effect, it only allows you to artificially trigger a redraw.

In order to properly trigger a redraw, use `ngZone` :

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

...

constructor(public zone: NgZone) { ... }
...

this.items = items;
this.isLoading = false;
this.zone.run(() => { // The magic line
    console.log('items N. Items ' + this.items.length, new Date())
});
```

Comment: I still have to find the call "out of Angular's world" but I have tried this solution and it worked just fine. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Note that `ngDoCheck` runs on change detection cycle that potentially affects the component. So it runs once after `ngOnInit` and then is called again by something else (perhaps mouse movement? hovering over something? click? it's hard to say for sure without stackblitz reproduction of your issue) but it seems it's not forced from the inside of your async call to your service. And if change detection is not triggered, the DOM won't be updated, hence you won't see your components. You don't show us what change detection strategy you're using either, and there are some properties you're using within your template as well which affect the layout of the component which can cause the issue.

Try using [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) to manually force checking for changes after  the `isLoading = false` part of your code. This will help you figure out if that's the change detection issue or something else. If it starts working, I'd suggest reading more about [change detection](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#using-change-detection-hooks) and angular [lifecycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) in the official docs to figure out how to fix this - I won't cover it better than they do :)

Comment: The detection strategy is the default one. I have added `checkNoChanges()` right after `isLoading = false` and it throws an exception as it has to do when a change is detected. The properties in the template are not affecting because I also tried to leave the HTML only with the piece of code for the list, nothing more and the issue still happens.